# <p:datatable> without borders and column headers

Tags: css, primefaces

I would need a datatable without borders and column headers. But I can't seem to get rid of the column headers. Below is my codes.

**CSS**

```
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data tr,
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data-empty tr,
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data td,
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data-empty td
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data th {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    styleClass="borderless" id="datatable_attributes"
    value="#{pc_Cr1002.w_currency.att_list}" var="varatt_list">
</p:datatable>
```

**html**

```
<div id="datatable_attributes" class="ui-datatable ui-widget borderless">
        <div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper"><table role="grid">
        <thead id="datatable_attributes_head"><tr role="row">
        <th id="datatable_attributes:att_col1" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><span></span></th><th id="datatable_attributes:att_col2" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><span></span></th><th id="datatable_attributes:att_col4" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" style="width:20px"><span></span></th><th id="datatable_attributes:att_col3" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><span></span></th></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody id="datatable_attributes_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content"><tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row">
```

Comment: Can you share the generated html?

Comment: @Mr. Alien, I have edited my post. See under html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to add space in your css classes declaration like this:
    **.ui-datatable .borderless**
because  folowing your code  have only .borderless class not
    .ui-datatable.borderless

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I don't think thats the problem. (:

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by overriding css, for example: remove column headers(also remove border)

```
<style type="text/css">
                #full_path\:datatable_attributes thead{
                    display:none !important;  
                }
            </style>
```

Comment: @hahagal it work fine with my project, you should post the code you have tried.